# ParserError: Expected primary expression indicating "payable"

Tags: solidity, payable

this is the solidity version:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
```

this is the function that throws error:

```
function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) external {
        if (withdrawAmount<1000000000000000000){
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdrawAmount);
        }
    }
```

**Error Message:** ParserError: Expected primary expression.

terminal underlines `payable`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a compiler version < 0.6.0.

The payable cast was introduced in [0.6.0](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/060-breaking-changes.html).

> Conversions from address to address payable are now possible via
> payable(x), where x must be of type address

If you want to use this syntax, use a more recent compiler version (> 0.6.0) .

Comment: I mentioned the version in the question.

Comment: pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

Comment: No, this is your file pragma, meaning that you allow compilation by a compiler version 0.4.22 to 0.9.0 (excluded) , your actual compiler version can be any version in the range. Given your error, you are actually using a compiler version < 0.6.0. Can you show your truffle configuration file ? especially the compiler settings if it is present ?